# Unit Test Mathf.Sine C# / Unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, math-functions

I am trying to write down a unit test to check if a new vector3 returns (cos(angle), 0, sin(angle)). So if pass angle = 0, it should returns (1,0,0).

I know it is something related to the Episilon, but I don't know how to formulate it.

Here is my code:

```
public Vector3 SetForceDirection(float angleInDegrees) 
    {
        float angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        
        return new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angleInRadians), 0, Mathf.Sin(angleInRadians));
    }
```

And my unit test:

```
void SetforceDirection_Angle0_Return_1_0_0() 
    {
        CtrlHorizontal _ctrlHorizontal = new CtrlHorizontal();

        Vector3 result = _ctrlHorizontal.SetForceDirection(0);

        Assert.That(result == new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: note that [`Vector3` `==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) has only a precision of `0.00001` ;) so epsilon shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Thanks @derHugo, I didn't know that. But the test is not passing and I am a little lost :(

Comment: What is the actual value of that `result` that you are asserting?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, it is Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angleInRadians), 0, Mathf.Sin(angleInRadians));

Comment: I mean, what are the actual values in that vector? I agree, they should be 1,0,0 and the assert should succeed

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thanks for your attention. Bellow, Ermiq explained me exactly why I am having problems with my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Debug.Log` to check what values `Mathf.Sin()/Cos()` return actually. The default precision used for `Vector3.ToString()` is 5 digits after the dot, iirc. To get higher precision in the debug logs, use

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(1.1234567891011, 0.00000001, 2.2222222222);
Debug.Log(v.ToString("F10"));
```

This should print the vector values with 10 digits after the dot.

So, what's actually happening?
Let's take for example the angle 90 degrees. The result of `Mathf.Cos()` will be:

```
tmp1 = 90f * Mathf.Deg2Rad; // 1.570769
tmp2 = Mathf.Cos(tmp1); // -4.371139E-08
```

So, `Mathf.Cos()` returns `-4.37139E-08` rather than `0`. The reason is floating points precision limit. It breaks a lot of things in computer science.
The results you get from `Mathf.Sin()/Cos()` with angles like 0, 90, 120 won't give you 0's and 1's, instead they will give you numbers like 4.371139E-08. This value is very very very close to zero but it's not a zero. So, when you compare such results to the `new Vector` 1, 0 and 0 in your code the equation fails.
Although, the `Vector3 == Vector3` operation in Unity already should apply some rounding so the values that are really close to each other will be treated as equal. As opposed to `Vector3.Euals()` which does the exact comparison.
Here is the source code of the `Vector3 == Vector3` operation from Unity's source code repo: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs

```
// Returns true if the vectors are equal.
public static bool operator==(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs)
{
    // Returns false in the presence of NaN values.
    float diff_x = lhs.x - rhs.x;
    float diff_y = lhs.y - rhs.y;
    float diff_z = lhs.z - rhs.z;
    float sqrmag = diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y + diff_z * diff_z;
    return sqrmag < kEpsilon * kEpsilon;
}
```

As you can see, it checks if the squared difference between the vectors values is less than `kEpsilon * kEpsilon` ( `kEpsilon = 0.00001`, so the squared value is `0.000000001` ).
The tricky thing here is `Mathf.Cos()` of 90 degrees might return `0.00001`, and the `==` operation will compare `0.00001 * 0.00001 < kEpsilon * kEpsilon` and it will return false, because these values are the same actually, so the result of the operation

```
Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(1, 0, 0); // your "checkout" vector
Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(1.00001, 0, 0); // the result of Mathf.Cos()/Sin() in your code
// in the Vector3 == Vector3 operation Unity does:
float sqrmag = 0.00001 * 0.00001 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0;
return sqrmag < kEpsilon * kEpsilon;
```

`0.000001 * 0.000001` is not less than `kEpsilon * kEpsilon` so you get the result where the vectors are not the same.

So, you'll need to compare the vectors in some other way. As an option, you could try `Mathf.Approximately(float a, float b)` ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html ) to compare each `x, y, z` values of the vectors separately instead of using `Vector3 == Vector3`.